Find the minimum total sum of distances between paired nodes in an unweighted tree
I am a beginner learning algorithms and currently working on a problem about finding the total sum of shortest distances in an unweighted tree. Here's the specific scenario:
The tree has nodes that belong to three different colors: red, yellow, and blue. The number of nodes for each color is the same. I want to pair each red node with a blue node and find the total sum of their shortest distances.
I have checked previous post but only seen questions regrading calculating distance between two specific nodes. So far, I am using BFS to traverse each node, but I'm stuck on how to record the unpaired blue and red nodes and compute the total shortest distances efficiently. Should I be using dynamic programming for this? I am not sure if my strategy is correct or not.
I would really appreciate any hints or guidance. Thank you so much in advance!

Just do be sure. You each red node will be connected with one blue node and vice versa? And you want to minimize the sum of all distances between those?

Yes that's correct. And every red node will only be matched with one blue node and vice versa

not sure if my strategy is correct no telling without you presenting it. My first idea: (Rooted tree?) For a leaf red or blue, pair with the lowest ancestor with complementary colour. Can this prevent a pairing neccessary for any minimal total sum?

Root the tree arbitrarily and perform a depth-first search. At each node, find the number of red and blue nodes in its subtree that have not yet been paired (this can be computed directly from the results of its children).
Next, pair as many nodes as possible (i.e. the number of pairs here is the minimum of the number of red nodes and the number of blue nodes). Add the number of remaining unpaired nodes to the total distance sum as these nodes need to traverse the edge to the parent on its path to the matching node.
This solution is O(V + E) or just O(V) since E = V - 1 in a tree.

Let me clarify --

Root the tree arbitrarily -> does that mean I should do V times search and set different node as the root each time?
Why choose dfs over bfs?


@jack94243 1. Root the tree arbitrarily just means choose any node as the root (to start the traversal from). 2. DFS is more suitable because we need the results of the children to process the parent. In general, it's rare for BFS to be used for tree problems.
